# How can I insert the correct ec2 instance ID into a dynamic Cloudwatch Dashboard using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

Background: My organization has multiple AWS accounts that, and within that we have multiple "environments" which we call beta and test. *The instances are rebuilt weekly and instance IDs change*. So the "Name" tag of a collections of EC2 instances in account 1 will look like this:

```
profileserver-account1-beta
profileserver-account1-test
domaincontroller-account1-beta
domaincontroller-account1-test
```

and in account 2 it'll have the same servers, but with "account2" in the name.

MY PROBLEM: I'm trying to build a cloudwatch dashboard with Terraform in our IaC. I want/need the "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" resource block to iterate over everything and create two dashboards. One for beta, and one for test. I am able to create multiple dashboards, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the instance ID's passed properly into each one.

main.tf:

```
data "aws_instances" "profile_instance" {
  for_each = var.environment

  instance_tags = {
    Name = "profileserver-${var.account}-${each.value}"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "cloudwatch_dash" {
  for_each = var.environment
  dashboard_name = "Dashboard-${each.value}"
  dashboard_body = jsonencode({
    widgets: [
        {
            height: 5,
            width: 6,
            y: 0,
            x: 6,
            type: "metric",
            properties: {
                view: "timeSeries",
                metrics: [
                    [ "AWS/ElasticBeanstalk", "RootFilesystemUtil", "EnvironmentName", "profileserver-${var.account}-${each.value}", "InstanceId", "data.aws_instances.profile_instance.ids[0]" ]
                ],
                region: "us-east-1",
                stacked: false,
                title: "Profile Server File System Usage"
            }
        },
  .
  .
  .
}
```

My problem is two-fold:

1. how do I make sure all beta servers are listed on the beta dashboard, and test servers on the test dashboard?
2. how do I ensure the InstanceId is actually populated? Currently on my dashboard source code the metrics show as the exact code, and NOT the data I want pulled:

```
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "data.aws_instances.profileserver-account1-beta.ids[0]" ]
```

I'm very new and unexperienced in Terraform (or any IAC) but I tried lots of different things to troubleshoot this. I had the JSON in a separate file at first, then I placed under jsonencode. All that did was make writing variables a little easier. I attempted to place a variable inside a variable, but that apparently is not allowed...

Comment: Have you tried using `data.aws_instances.profileserver-account1-beta.ids[0]` without the quotes?

Comment: When I do that I get "Because data.aws_instances.profileserver has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad. How about: `data.aws_instances.profile_instance[each.key].ids[0]`?

Comment: @Marko-E (Not sure how to tag you, lol) Sorry for my slow reply! I work from home and kids woke up. THAT WORKED. Thank you SO much. I can't believe it was so easy and stupid. Sincerest appreciation, I've been working on this for days trying different things.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens all the time. :) I'll post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data source is using `for_each`, that means the result will be a set of key value pairs. To fetch the values, a key is necessary. Since both the data source and the resource are using the same variable with `for_each`, the correct value provided by the data source for a given key can be fetched like this:

```
data "aws_instances" "profile_instance" {
  for_each = var.environment

  instance_tags = {
    Name = "profileserver-${var.account}-${each.value}"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "cloudwatch_dash" {
  for_each = var.environment
  dashboard_name = "Dashboard-${each.value}"
  dashboard_body = jsonencode({
    widgets: [
        {
            height: 5,
            width: 6,
            y: 0,
            x: 6,
            type: "metric",
            properties: {
                view: "timeSeries",
                metrics: [
                    [ "AWS/ElasticBeanstalk", "RootFilesystemUtil", "EnvironmentName", "profileserver-${var.account}-${each.value}", "InstanceId", data.aws_instances.profile_instance[each.key].ids[0] ]
                ],
                region: "us-east-1",
                stacked: false,
                title: "Profile Server File System Usage"
            }
        },
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: I need to investigate more, but do you know off hand (and I'll create a new question if I can't figure it out) why this would only work on the Linux instances but not the Windows ones?

Comment: Not really sure, are the Windows instances also in ElasticBeanstalk? Can you try getting the metric value from the UI just to check if it's even possible?

Comment: I figured out the issue (it took a day and and a half because our system was down and I couldn't communicate with aws through terraform). When the code is looping through, it's running into instances that are Stopped. So it finds profileserver-account1-beta, but if beta is OFF then it errors out.

Unfortunately that means I need to find a new solution to pull instance IDs :( Thanks again for your help on this.